# How do I take a webflow .zip file and have it be usable in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, webflow

I have a react app that is being built and someone else made a page in webflow that needs to be added as the home page. What would be the best way to do this?

I've tried just putting the html pages into my 'pages' folder, but I get errors when I then try to launch them through App.js. Appfairy seemed nice, but it looks like it has been discontinued. I am trying to avoid having to convert all the html into js.